# $\frac34-(\frac34)^2+(\frac34)^3-...+(-1)^{n-1}(\frac34)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $A_n=\frac34-(\frac34)^2+(\frac34)^3-...+(-1)^{n-1}(\frac34)^n$ and $B_n=1-A_n$, then find the least value of $n_0, n_0\in N$ such that $B_n>A_n,\forall n\ge n_0$.

My attempt:$A_n$ is a Geometric Progression. So, $$A_n=\frac37\left[1-\left(-\frac34\right)^n\right]$$Also,$$1-A_n>A_n$$
So,$$A_n<\frac12$$
So,$$1-\left(-\frac34\right)^n<\frac76$$
So, $$\left(-\frac34\right)^n>-\frac16$$
Putting values of $n$ as $1,2,3...$, but nothing concrete is appearing.

Comment: taking the log of both sides to yield inequality in n

Comment: @D.R.Logarithm for a negativ value?

Comment: "Logarithm for a negativ value?"  multiply both sides by $-1$ first.  If $n$ is even equation holds.  If $n$ is odd we need $(\frac 34)^n < \frac 16$.  Perfect for logs. $n\le \frac{\ln\frac 16}{ln \frac 34} = \frac {0-\ln 6}{\ln 3-\ln 4}\approx 6.228$... Or brute force.  $6*3^n < 4^n$ or $3^{n+1}< 2^{2n-1}$.  $2^{2n-1}= 2,8,32,128,512,2048,8192, etc$ and $3^{n+1} = 9,27,81,273,819,2457$..... So $n = 6$.

Comment: @fleablood when diving by ln(3/4), inequality reverses. Otherwise pretty neat method. Thanks.

Comment: Also, are values 8, 27 etc allowed as n is even? I thought we were applying brute force for odd values of n.

Comment: We are interested in odd powers so the even tests are redundant.  ... oh, right.  Typo... $n \ge 6.22$ so odd $n \ge 7$ but even $n =6$ is also good.  So $n_0 = 6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are correct to this point, then you could proceed as follows:

If $n$ is odd then $n=2m+1$

$$\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{2m+1}>-\frac16$$

So $\left(-\frac34\right )^{2m}<\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac43$, where we multiplyed the inequality with $-\frac43$. Keep in mind that this changes the direction of the relation.

So we get:

$$\left(\left(-\frac34\right)^{2}\right)^m=\left(\frac{9}{16}\right)^m<\frac{4}{18}$$

Now take the logarithm and solve for $m$.

$$m\log\left(\frac9{16}\right)<\log\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)\Leftrightarrow m>\frac{\log\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)}{\log\left(\frac{9}{16}\right)}$$

Again $\log(x)$ is negativ for $0<x<1$ so it changes the sign.

If $n$ is even, then the LHS is positive and the RHS is negative, so always true.

Comment: But n keeps alternating between even and odd. The inequality fails at 1,3,5 etc. it's holding for 2,4,6.

Comment: m is coming out to be greater than 0.38. It means we can take m as 1. So, n=3. But n can't be 3.

Comment: @Ramit Yes, I made a mistake. Numerator and denominator have to be swapped. Also I might have done a mistake.

Comment: oh, I see. I'll recalculate.

Comment: So, m is coming out to be greater than 2.6. So, m=3. So, n=7, which is pretty much the consensus. Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty neat method. +1. I wonder if there is a way to solve it without using log table. (though we are only using log2 and log 3)

Comment: I do not know a way around the logarithm here. I think for exact values you need the logarithm at some point. Maybe an inductive proof does the trick.

Comment: You need the concept of logarithm but as these are small values you can just try values so that $(\frac 34)^n < \frac 16$.  $\frac 12 < (\frac 34)^2 = \frac {9}{16}<\frac 35$ and $\frac 14 < (\frac 34)^4 < \frac {9}{25}<\frac 25$ and $\frac 1{16}< (\frac 34)^8 < \frac 4{15}< \frac 16$ so $5 \le n \le 8$ and probably closer to $8$.  Test $7$ and $5$ if necessary.

Comment: @fleablood- why are we checking for even values of n, when the inequality we are working with holds for odd values of n?

Answer (score 1):

The negative terms in the sequence $u_n:=\left(-\frac34\right)^n$ aren't $>-\frac16$ until their moduli are $<\frac16$, which happens once $n$ is an odd number $\ge\frac{\ln 6}{\ln\frac43}\approx 6.23$, so take $n_0=6$.

Comment: For, n=6, it's anyways true. So, $n_0$ should be 6.

Comment: @Ramit Thanks; fixed.

Comment: How did you reach that inequality $\frac{ln6}{ln\frac43}$?

Comment: Is there a way to solve it without using log table?

Comment: @Ramit In response to your last two comments, you can just work through powers of $-3/4$ until their moduli are $<1/6$.

Comment: You need $(\frac 34)^n< \frac 16;n$ odd.  That means $6*3^n < 4^n$ or $3^{n+1} < 2^{2n-1}$.  Knowing that $3^2 \approx 2^3$ we want $\frac {n+1}2 \approx \frac {2n-1}3$ so $3n+3\approx 4n-2$ so $n\approx 5$.  And $3^{6}= 729$ while $2^9=512 < 729$ so $n=5$ is too small.  But $3^8 = 9*729 < 16*512=2^{13}$ so $n=7$ is good. And as $n= 6$ even is good. $n_0=6$.

Comment: @fleablood- you are on fire!

Answer (score 1):

$$(-\frac34)^n>-\frac16 $$

is satisfied for $n=6$ because for $n=6$ it is obvious and  $$(-\frac34)^7=-.1334..> -1/6$$

And the inequality stays valid for $n\ge 6$ because the sequence terms $(-3/4)^n$ are either positive or decreasing in absolute value.

Comment: For, n=6, it's anyways true. So, $n_0$ should be 6.

Comment: How to reach n=7 by the way? Is it by putting values? Isn't that cumbersome?

Comment: The positive terms are obvious and the negative terms I just plugged in. I could have gone by logarithms of absolute values but it did not worth it in this case.

Comment: Sorry, plug in means?

Comment: evaluate$ (-3/4)^n$ for $n=1,3,5,7$